# Sorting std::map based on the data (map->vector->sort)

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, vector

I want to sort a `std::map` based on the data (second field). However the second field itself is a structure and I want to sort based on one of its elements. Based on what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500962/howto-sort-stdmap) and its [reference](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/275617-stl-stdmap-and-sorting-using-value_compare/?view=findpost&p=2708722), decided to copy the map to a vector and then use `std::sort`. Here is the class implementtion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

class foo() {
    foo() {}
    void bar()
    {
      aDeltaMap theDeltaMap;
      // insert some elements to theDeltaMap
      aDeltaVector theDeltaVec( theDeltaMap.begin(), theDeltaMap.end() );
      std::sort(theDeltaVec.begin(), theDeltaVec.end(), descend_rep<deltaPair>() );   //ERROR
    }
private:
    typedef struct entry {
      entry( int r, int mc ) : rep(r), missCounter(mc) {}
      int rep;
      int missCounter;
    } aDeltaEntry;

    typedef std::map< int, aDeltaEntry > aDeltaMap;
    typedef std::pair< int, aDeltaEntry > deltaPair;
    typedef std::vector< deltaPair > aDeltaVector;
    struct descend_rep
      : std::binary_function<deltaPair,deltaPair,bool>
      {
         inline bool operator()(const deltaPair& lhs, const deltaPair& rhs) { return lhs.second.rep > rhs.second.rep; };
      };
 };
```

At the line of sort function, I get this error

```
 error C2275: illegal use of this type as an expression
 error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

What did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is that `descent_rep` is not a class template, so you need to replace

```
descend_rep<deltaPair>()
```

by

```
descend_rep()
```

You should make `descend_rep`'s `bool operator()` `const` too, since comparing its operands does not change its state.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it is not necessary to write a template because I have only one data type. Then I forgot to remove the template