# How to Find Column Average from 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find average of each column (i.e. {5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10} and print for each row:. following is the code. I keep on getting 0 on print and I am sure there is something wrong somewhere. Any help would be great. thanks .

```
   int ScoreAverage() // average of artist scores
{
    const int A1_SIZE = 5,  A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;
    string Artist[A1_SIZE]={ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
    int Scores[A2_ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] = {{5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},{8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
     {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},{5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}};

     cout << "\n\n\t-------------------------------------------" << endl;
     cout << "\t\tAverage Scores by Artist"<< endl;
     cout << "\t===========================================" << endl;

    int total = 0;
    double average, faverage;


   for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
   {
     cout << "\n\t" << Artist[x] << "\t\t";

        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {

            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
            {
               total+=Scores[row][col];
            }
        average = total/10;
        average = faverage;

        }
        average = total = 0;
        cout << "\tAverage ... " << faverage << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up row and col in your Scores[][]. You then set everything to 0 with average = faverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ScoreAverage() // average of artist scores
{
    const int A1_SIZE = 5,  A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;
    string Artist[A1_SIZE]={ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
    int Scores[A2_ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] = {{5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},{8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
    {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},{5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}};

    cout << "\n\n\t-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tAverage Scores by Artist"<< endl;
    cout << "\t===========================================" << endl;

    int total = 0;
    float faverage;


    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        cout << "\n\t" << Artist[x] << "\t\t";

        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            total+=Scores[x][col];
        }
        faverage = (float)total / 10.0f;

        average = total = 0;
        cout << "\tAverage ... " << faverage << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Should do it.

Note: your "int average" is completely useless here, and I would eliminate it altogether.

Edit: your indexing is totally screwed up...

Edit2: adding std::map into the equation

```
std::map <string, float> artistList;
artistList.insert(Artist[x], fAverage);
```

then sort the list accordingly (see [HowTo sort std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500962/howto-sort-stdmap))

Comment: @mani Well another error is that you are mixing up rows and columns. Try looking at your code again.

Comment: @ john 5 rows and 10 columns, and 5 rows assigned to artist names.. with your updated code i am getting 0 as average. :(

Comment: @mani okay, I ran the code now, there was an indexing error with your triple loops. You need one loop for each artist, and one for the scores per artist. You had a loop over all scores for all artists, so every artist would get the same value.

Comment: @mani Note: the code I pasted now works, I tested it here on my system.

Comment: @mani yes 5 rows, 10 columns, so why does your code say `for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)` and `for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)`? See my answer.

Comment: thanks John, how would i compare these average values and sort them out ?.

Comment: I am looking at resources,.. i guess I would have to store these averages into an array and then compare those arrays ?!. but its confusing..

Comment: How would i store these generated values into an array for instance, storing all these value in an array of 5 items.. AverageScores[];?

Comment: std::vector<> is always a possibility, or a std::map, but meh, no vote on my answer, why would I bother?

Comment: @anthon I cant vote yet, new here, though i accepted the answer :). I am able to find the maximum and minimum, the only problem I am having is sorting so it co related with the names (string array) (Artist[A1_SIZE]

Comment: @mani I updated with how I would do it. Note that you cannot sort it directly, but rather have to create the sorting algorithm yourself (for a small amount of entries go with BubbleSort)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.

```
 const int A1_SIZE = 5,  A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;
 string Artist[A1_SIZE]={ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
 int Scores[A2_ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] = {{5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},{8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
 {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},{5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}};

 cout << "\n\n\t-------------------------------------------" << endl;
 cout << "\t\tAverage Scores by Artist"<< endl;
 cout << "\t===========================================" << endl;

double total = 0;
double average = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {
       total += Scores[i][j];
   }
   average = total/10;
   cout << "\n\t" << Artist[i] << "\t\t";
   cout << "\tAverage ... " << average << endl;
   average = 0;
   total = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method One**

```
int ScoreAverage() // average of artist scores
{
    // not necessary to have 2 row size constants since these are related
    // could make this even better by putting the artist name and scores in a class
    const int ROWSIZE = 5;  
    const int COLSIZE = 10;
    std::string Artist[ROWSIZE] = { "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
    int Scores[ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] = {
                                            {5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},
                                            {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
                                            {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
                                            {5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                            {5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}
                                        };

    std::cout << "\n\n\t-------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\tAverage Scores by Artist"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t===========================================" << std::endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < ROWSIZE; x++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t" << Artist[x] << "\t\t";
        int total = std::accumulate(std::begin(Scores[row]), std::end(Scores[row]), 0);
        double average = static_cast<double>(total) / static_cast<double>(COLSIZE);
        std::cout << "\tAverage ... " << average << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Method Two**

```
class Artist
{
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    std::vector<int> m_Scores;

public:
    // constructors and accessors here

    double Average() const
    {
        int total = std::accumulate(m_Scores.begin(), m_Scores.end(), 0);
        return static_cast<double>(total) / static_cast<double>(m_Scores.size());
    }   
};

void printAverage(const Artist& a)
{
    std::cout << "\n\t" << a.GetName() << "\t\t" << a.Average() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Artist> artists(5);
    // fill in artists here
    std::for_each(artists.begin(), artists.end(), printAverage);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

`average = faverage;`

This is overlaying what was previously computed in average. Worse of all, `faverage` is not even initialized!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only have row and columns so why three nested loops? Makes no sense.

Replace all constants sizes with variables.

Don't divide by integers!

Actually print the contents of average, faverage is zero because its never set to anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Having taken the trouble to write

```
const int A1_SIZE = 5,  A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;
```

why did you not carry that through and write this?

```
for (int x=0; x<A1_SIZE; x++)

for (int row = 0; row < A2_ROWSIZE; row++)

for (int col = 0; col < A2_COLSIZE; col++)
```

Would have fixed at least one error.