# How do I find the average of a column in a list?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a list of vectors currently, stored as a `std::list<Vec3f> unsortedRays;`

```
-4.5 4.5 -8.66025 
-3.5 4.5 -8.66025 
-2.5 4.5 -8.66025 
-1.5 4.5 -8.66025 
-0.5 4.5 -8.66025
```

I'm generating these earlier in the program and can calculate the size beforehand (or after too).

How do I find the average of each column (0, 1, 2)?

In Python, I can do:

```
x_avg = np.mean(column(list, 0))
y_avg = np.mean(column(list, 1))
z_avg = np.mean(column(list, 2))
```

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836744/4039852) but haven't been able to get it to work so far.

Edit:

Here's what I have so far in my `simple.cpp` file:

```
std::list<Vec3f> unsortedRays;

void generateRays() {
  for (size_t y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      Vec3f direction;
      float dir_x =  (x + 0.5) -  width/2.;
      float dir_y = -(y + 0.5) + height/2.;
      float dir_z = -height/(2.*tan(fov/2.));

      direction = Vec3f(dir_x, dir_y, dir_z);

      unsortedRays.push_back (direction);
    }
  }
}

static void sortRays() {
  const int rows = width * height, columns = 3;
  std::vector<double> matrix;
  double sum=0;

  for (auto const& i : unsortedRays) { // for each row
    //std::vector<double> row;
    //row.push_back[i];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) { // for each column, or "value"
      double value = i[j];
      //std::cout << value;

      matrix.push_back (value);
      sum += value;
      //std::cout << "sum: " << sum  << "\n";
    }
  }
  const double quantity = unsortedRays.size();
  const double average = sum / quantity;

  std::cout << "average: " << average  << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you found a reasonable answer. You should show your implementation of its recommended solution so we can see what went wrong and differentiate your question from it. Sucks to have a question be closed as a duplicate of a question you've already consulted.

Comment: Are you using a `struct` to read this in or `std::vector` or `std::array` or what?  Is this `std::list<std::vector<double>>`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no ready-to-go solution from the std libraryy. 
The 5-minute solution is to write the function on your own. It's an easy task.
If you need fast access to matrix operations (multiplication etc.) I recommend taking a look at the 3. party libraries Eigen and newmat11

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `std::list<Vec3f> unsortedRays;` currently. Adapting your code results in `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::list<Vec3f>' (aka 'list<vec<3, float> >') and 'double')`: I assume I should be passing in `unsortedRays` directly into the loop?

Comment: @user4581301 I've updated the question with some code. I'm new to C++ and doing this as a proof of concept so apologies in advance for bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
double c1, c2, c3;
double sum1=0.0, sum2=0.0, sum3=0.0;
while (my_file >> c1 >> c2 >> c3)
{
    std::vector<double> row;
    row.push_back(c1);
    row.push_back(c2);
    row.push_back(c3);
    matrix.push_back(row);
    sum1 += c1;
    sum2 += c2;
    sum3 += c3;
}
const double quantity = matrix.size();
const double average_c1 = sum1 / quantity;
const double average_c2 = sum2 / quantity;
const double average_c3 = sum3 / quantity;
```

The above code calculates the sum of each column as the data is read, and stores the values into a matrix.

The average of each column is calculated using the sum variables for the appropriate column and the amount of data read in.

Comment: I'm able to iterate through columns and rows now but I'm having trouble with the push_back call: `error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back' matrix.push_back(value);`

Comment: Look at the types.  In the above example, `matrix` is composed of `vector<double>`.  In order to do `matrix.push_back()`, the `value` must be a vector of double.

Comment: Ah, yes. That resolves all the errors. I've updated the code above - maybe I'm missing something obvious but the result currently only saves the last column - I think I have to re-work your `double c1, c2, c3` somehow so the for loop puts the right average in the right one.